# External linkage in C

Tags: c

K&R says:

> by default external variables and functions have the property that all references to them by the same name, even from functions compiled separately, are references to same thing

Please explain what this means, I don't understand it

Comment: Excuse me, are you new to c? In my opinion, K&R is not a suitable introductory book for newbies.

Comment: However, making the effort to understand K&R will give you a really good grasp of C. I say keep at it.

Comment: I'm not against the question. I noticed that ashma had asked several questions. Sincerely wish he can use a more appropriate book for him/her.

Answer (score 5):

Consider two functions:

```
extern int extern_sqr(int i) { return i * i; }
static int static_dbl(int i) { return i * 2; }
```

Then people who refer to `extern_sqr` will be referring to that function.  This is opposed to `static` linkage, where only people from within the "translation unit" (roughly the file it's defined) can access the function `static_dbl`.

It turns out, that the `extern` is implied by default in c.  So, you would get the same behavior, if you wrote:

```
int extern_sqr(int i) { return i * i; }
```

Newer C standards still require a "function declaration" so, usually in a header file somewhere, you'll encounter:

```
int extern_sqr(int i);  // Note: 'i' is optional
```

Which says "somewhere, in some other translation unit, I have a function called `extern_sqr`.

The same logic applies to variables.

Comment: You may also add that in the function declaration, the variable names are optional as you may see
int extern_sqr(int);
instead.

Comment: @Maximus : edited, thanks.  I could also go into parameter types being _completely_ optional, depending on which standard, but why confuse things :)

Answer (score 0):

external variables and functions are global, i.e. hold the same values (for variables) or definitions (for functions) even when called from different *.c files within your program.