# How to over come the warning fun defined but not used

Tags: c

I am calling a function in one file

```
a = fun(a,b);
```

I am having the #define of that function in other file

```
 #define fun fun1
```

I am defining that function in another file

```
static int fun1(int a, int b)
{
   -------------
   -------------
 }
```

But compiler complaints

> 'fun1' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]

Its strange for me that compiler complaints about this.

Comment: if it's static, how are you using it in a different file?

Comment: Do you also use a header file? If so, what's it's content? Show full code, please.

Answer (score 10):

```
static int fun1(int a, int b)
```

`static`means that this function can be only used in this file. Remove the `static` and try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093558/external-linkage-in-c discusses the differences between internal and external linkage.

Comment: If i remove static its giving multiple definition of fun1

Comment: @rock_buddy Then there must be another definition of `fun1` somewhere, find out where it is first. Or, did you put the definition of `fun1` in a header?

Comment: No there is no other definition of fun1. first defined here also showing in the same line number.

Comment: Ya the definition in the header

Comment: It's undefined reference to fun1

Comment: @rock_buddy That's another problem, buddy. Don't put function definition in the header, because it will be included in multiple files, which leads to multiple definition error. Put only the declaration in the header and put the definition in one of the .c files.

Comment: @rock_buddy Back to the start, `static` means the function can only be used in this file, so other files can't see it, so it won't generate the multiple definition error. But the problem of putting it in the header is, other files includes the header will also have the definition of the function, but they don't need it. That's why you got the warning in the first place.

Comment: @rock_buddy Well, if it solves your problem, why not accepting why answer by clicking the checkmark, it's the SO way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems here: The first about that warning, because in the other source file you don't actually *use* the function. The second problem is that you marked the function as `static`, which means that it will only be available in that specific source file.

If you want to be able to call functions defined in other source files (translation units as they are really called) then you can't make functions `static`.